# Count tokens of jsonl file for fine tuning gpt

Tags: json, token, openai-api, fine-tuning

How can I calculate token of my JSONL file which is created after running openai command in terminal. I do know that when we run command for creating modal it shows stats about taokens usage and pricing but I couldn’t see the stats because the client side sinnection hungup.

So how can I calculate tokens count as I want to estimate the price that is going to cost me for fine tuning

How can I calculate token of my JSONL file which is created after running openai command in terminal. I do know that when we run command for creating modal it shows stats about taokens usage and pricing but I couldn’t see the stats because the client side sinnection hungup.

So how can I calculate tokens count as I want to estimate the price that is going to cost me for fine tuning